# Controlling z-index for multiple panels in javascript

Tags: yui, panel

We have to deal with multiple panels on the website ( refer to the screenshot below ).

The problem is we need to make the **panel that users select on top of other panels**

We can manually try to control the z-index of each panel, but is there an easier way to do this?

Env:
- YUI 2.7
- IE7/8, FF3.x

[multiple panels screenshot](http://www.screencast.com/users/lchandra/folders/Jing/media/ec68e280-a088-4543-88d1-10f266fa7a96)

[panels img http://www.screencast.com/users/lchandra/folders/Jing/media/ec68e280-a088-4543-88d1-10f266fa7a96](http://www.screencast.com/users/lchandra/folders/Jing/media/ec68e280-a088-4543-88d1-10f266fa7a96)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re: "is there an easier way to do this?"

Yes, use the [YUI Overlay Manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/overlaymanager.html)